# Check if two types are the same without template instantiations

Tags: c++, performance, reinventing-the-wheel, template

Below is my attempt to check if two types are the same without template instantiations.

```
#include <cstddef>
template<class, class> struct twoTypes;
template<class T> std::size_t isSame(twoTypes<T,T>*);
bool isSame(void*);

template<class T, class U>
using checkIfSame = decltype(isSame(static_cast<twoTypes<T,U>*>(0)));
```

And to check if they're the same, checkIfSame's size will be compared to std::size_t's size:

```
static_assert(sizeof(checkIfSame<int,int>) == sizeof(std::size_t)); //They're the same
static_assert(sizeof(checkIfSame<const int,int>) == sizeof(bool)); //Not the same
```

Are there any cases where my code will give the wrong result? My benchmarks show my version compiling faster than `std::is_same`, but are there any ways to make it faster?

Comment: What benchmarks? What compiler version and flags? Why do you need this?

Comment: I used clang with the -ftime-trace flag. I'm mostly curious to see if my way would work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using clang or GCC ≥10, you can use the `__is_same(type1, type2)` intrinsic.

For portability:

```cpp
#if !defined(__is_same) && (!defined(__clang__) || !defined(__GNUC__) || __GNUC__ < 10)
#define IS_SAME(T1, T2) std::is_same_v<T1, T2>
#else
#define IS_SAME(T1, T2) __is_same(T1, T2)
#endif
```

Comment: I'll look into intrinsics, though I asked my question primarily to ask for evaluation of my method of checking if two types are the same.

Comment: I think it looks okay, but intrinsics should compile even faster.